# Combining multiple columns into one with strings in r

Tags: r, string, merge, multiple-columns

I have a dataset that has the date and time split into multiple columns, I was looking to put them all into one column to plot.  any help would be greatly appreciated, so far my data looks like this...

```
YY       MM        DD      HH       MM
2012     03        04      03       50
2012     03        04      03       40
2012     03        04      03       30
2012     03        04      03       20
2012     03        04      03       10
```

and would like it to look like this....

```
DateTime
2012-03-04 03:50
2012-03-04 03:40
2012-03-04 03:30
2012-03-04 03:20
2012-03-04 03:10
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at `paste()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `sprintf`

```
df1$DateTime <-do.call(sprintf, c(df1, 
      list(fmt = '%04d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d')))
df1$datetime
#[1] "2012-03-04 03:50" "2012-03-04 03:40" "2012-03-04 03:30" "2012-03-04 03:20" "2012-03-04 03:10"
```

Comment: @OscarTheGrouch  You can either use `$` or `[` to create a new column.  Updated the post

Comment: I have to wait 5 mins before accepting your solution, but thanks a ton!

Comment: @OscarTheGrouch  No problem.  Thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 0):

Another approach using `paste`.

```
text1 <- "YY       MM        DD      HH       MM
2012     03        04      03       50
2012     03        04      03       40
2012     03        04      03       30
2012     03        04      03       20
2012     03        04      03       10"

d1 <- read.table(text=text1, head=T, as.is=T, colClasses = rep("character", 5))

library(dplyr)

d1 %>% transmute(DateTime=paste(paste(YY, MM, DD, sep="-"),
                 paste(HH, MM.1, sep=":")))
```